# How long is the longest running anime series?

Tags: anime-production

I know that the Pokemon anime has over 800 episodes, and One Piece has 600+ episodes, but I've heard that they are not in the top 10 of anime with the most number of episodes.

So what anime is longest?

Comment: It's worth noting that the Pokemon anime is generally not considered a single anime, but rather to be broken up into distinct seasons - the original series (through the end of Johto), followed by Advanced Generation (Hoenn + Battle Frontier), DP (Sinnoh), and Best Wishes (Unova). The longest of those is the original series, clocking in at a "mere" 276 episodes.

Comment: Related topic: [Which is the manga series with the highest number of volumes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/22426) and [Are there any other Guinness world record holders?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/36384)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[Sazae-san](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sazae-san) (still ongoing) holds the [Guinness World Record](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/1000/longest-running-animated-tv-series) for the longest running animated television series at more than 7071 episodes. For a list of runner-ups, check [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_anime_series_by_episode_count).

Comment: For inquiring minds, there is [a list of every series with 100+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_anime_series_by_episode_count).

Comment: and since 1969 too, so time-wise it's much longer than any other series

Answer (score 3):

The longest series is 'Sazae-san'. It has 2255+7071+ episodes.

(The number '2255' is actually more accurate although it was achieved through bad math. There are actually [according to more recent numbers from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_anime_series_by_episode_count) wiki list] around 2390+ episodes. However, each episode consists of three separate stories/vignettes and can be counted as three separate episodes and that is where the 7000+ number comes from {2390 x 3 = 7170}. Furthermore, the [Sazae-san wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sazae-san) states it has aired every Sunday since 1969 so using your friend math you can see that 46 years x 52 Sundays per year = 2392 episodes)

Comment: Where did you get the figure 2255+ from? Also, this has already been answered by ʞɹɐzǝɹ and your post adds nothing new (maybe except that curious number).

Comment: -1, as @GaoWeiwei hgas mentioned ʞɹɐzǝɹ has already mentioned Sazae-san and you add 2255 to the number with no reference explaining this