# Which is the manga series with the highest number of volumes?

Tags: manga-production

There are some famous manga like [One Piece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Piece) have 77 volumes and are still ongoing or [Naruto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naruto) which has 72 volumes.

Which manga series is the one with the highest number of volumes ?

Comment: Related topic: [How long is the longest running anime series?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/7678) and [Are there any other Guinness world record holders?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/36384)

Answer (score 9):

As described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_manga_series_by_volume_count) the manga [Kochira Katsushika-ku Kameari Kōen-mae Hashutsujo (Kochikame)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kochira_Katsushika-ku_Kameari_K%C5%8Den-mae_Hashutsujo) is the manga series illustrated by [Osamu Akimoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osamu_Akimoto) with the highest number of volumes and ended on September 17, 2016 in the 42nd issue of the year, in commemoration of Kochikame's 40th anniversary. It was continuously serialized in Weekly Shōnen Jump since September 1976 with 1960 chapters collected into 200 [tankōbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tank%C5%8Dbon) volumes.